# use [Today] in a URL filter

Tags: 2013, list, url

Is it possible to pass "Today" in some shape or form to filter a SharePoint list as a URL parameter? I'd like to have a link that looks something like

```
http://www.contoso.com/sites/mylist/allitems.aspx?FilterField1=DateCreated&FilterValue1=[Today] .
```

I can't dynamically construct the URL as a string and pass the actual date value to the string because the URL is a parameter in a static XML file for a Windows 8.1 Live Tile.

Comment: why don't you create second list view with static filter [Today]?